# How can I uninstall Flask?

Tags: python, flask, uninstallation

I've been trying to uninstall Flask from my Mac, but get the following error:

```
sim1-3010:~ seanpatterson$ sudo uninstall Flask
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is     setuid or setgid
Preparing Uninstall...
Uninstall Began...
Uninstall Failed...
Reason: ErrorMissingBundle
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with pip ?

Comment: it depends on how you installed Flask

Answer (score 9):

1. If you installed flask with `pip`, use `pip uninstall flask`.
2. If you're not sure how you installed flask, but didn't use pip, try running this command:

   `python -c "import os, flask; print(os.path.dirname(flask.__file__))"`

Then, manually delete that entire directory from the filesystem.

Comment: I actually did do `sudo pip install Flask`, but a short time later, `sudo pip uninstall Flask` resulted in _Can't uninstall 'Flask'. No files were found to uninstall._ (An 'n' is missing from your first answer.) But your second, brute force answer came to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

```
#python 2.7 

pip uninstall flask   # in mac osx
```

## or

```
#python 3

pip3 uninstall flask   # in mac osx
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to manually remove

```
path/to/my/python2.7/site-packages/flask
```

and

```
/usr/local/bin/flask
```

which I found via `which flask`.  I'm assuming it will all be removed automatically if everything is set up on your computer correctly.